# pip list Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"

Tags: python, pip, anaconda3

```
C:\Users\Akhira kodam>pip list Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\Akhira kodam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"  "C:\Users\Akhira kodam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe" list': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

For some reason i have uninstalled the python from my system and I installed anaconda using the python of anaconda as system default

previously i installed various packages using pip although all of those packages are still accessible(importable) when i am using the pip i am getting this maybe the anacondas python may not have installed in that same file location as the previous idk what happened how do it fix It

Comment: Does the directory `C:\Users\Akhira kodam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python` still exist? If you have uninstalled that python version, remove that directory

Comment: This is in anaconda command prompt?

Comment: `pip` needs `python.exe` to run correctly. Frankly `pip` is a script which runs command `python.exe -m pip ...`